# How to convert spark response to JSON object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val input = sqlContext.read.json("input.json")
input.select("email", "first_name").where("email=='donny54@yahoo.com'").show()
```

I am getting following response

[image]

How can I get response as a JSON Object?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it to Json File : https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/spark-write-dataset-to-json-file-example/

Or if you prefer to show it as a Dataset of Json Strings, use the `toJSON` function :

```scala
input
  .select("email", "first_name")
  .where("email=='donny54@yahoo.com'")
  .toJSON()
  .show()
```

Comment: Thanks Rafeael for quick reply. As per your reply I am using 

input
  .select("email", "first_name")
  .where("email=='donny54@yahoo.com'")
  .toJson()
  .show() 

Getting below error  

 not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]])spray.json.JsValue.
[error] Unspecified value parameter writer.
[error]                 .toJson()
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: @SadasibaSahoo Sorry I made a typo, it was actually `toJSON()`, could you try ?

Comment: Cool ! don't hesitate to accept the answer. Cheers !